# Can't access form values via AJAX post

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I am posting a form to a ColdFusion action page via AJAX for processing. But for some reason my processing page is not seeing any of my form values.

```
<cfoutput>

<!--- Javascript that updates the notes in the DB --->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('##notesForm').submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            ajaxAddNotes();
        });

function ajaxAddNotes() {
            console.log("ajaxAddNotes function called");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: $('##notesForm').serialize(),
                url: "../actionpages/add_notes.cfm",
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $('.loader').show();
                },
                complete: function(){
                     $('.loader').hide(3000);
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("File successfully sent.");

                    $("##addFileResponse").append( "Note successfully added." );
                    PopulateNotesDIV();
                    },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });

</script>

    <form name="notesForm" id="notesForm">
    <textarea class='expanding' tabindex="18" name="tech_notes" id="tech_notes" cols="100" rows="5" >#get_ticket.tech_notes#</textarea><br />

            <input tabindex="0" type="submit" name="update-notes" id="update-notes" value="Update Notes" />
            <input type="hidden" value="#url.ticketID#" name="ticket_id" id="ticket_id">

             <div class="loader"><img class="loading-image" src="../images/loading.gif" /></div>
            <div class="response" id="addFileResponse"></div>

    </form>
</cfoutput>
```

This is the code on my processing page (I know I haven't cfqueryparam'd this query. Just testing at this point):

```
<cfdump var="#form#">

<!---Update Notes button was clicked so we now must update the notes section --->
<cfquery name="update_notes" datasource="#datasource#">
update closed_tickets
set tech_notes = '#form.tech_notes#'
where ticket_id = #form.ticket_id#
</cfquery>
```

Comment: What's the output of `<cfdump ....`? Use your browser's dev tools to check if the request is being made and what the response is.

Comment: It juest says: struct [empty]

Comment: And what parameters/values are being sent in the `POST` request, if any?

Comment: Can you put the submit button as the last element in the form?

Comment: I'm trying to pass the two input fields of my form: tech_notes & ticket_id

Comment: You're browser's dev tools can tell you if anything is being sent.

Comment: Same result: 500 (Element TECH_NOTES is undefined in FORM.)

Comment: Where in Chrome would that be?

Comment: Yes, even Firefox and IE.

Comment: Can you make these changes just to confirm something: 1. Use `ajaxAddNotes.apply(this)`, then 2. Use `$(this).serialize()`

Comment: So if I change my AJAX post to: type: "GET", I then see all my form variables as URL variables in my DEV tools. Then if I just change my CFQuery to call URL variables and not form variables, my processing page works just fine. I don't get it??

Comment: Do you need your js wrapped in cfoutput?

Comment: You did not confirm if the correct values are being sent in the `POST`. If they are, quite likely you have some redirection, such as CAS authentication, which is causing your posted data to be lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `contentType: false` is preventing the submission from being recognized as a form POST. Remove that setting and it will work. As John Whish explained in the comments:

> .. by default contentType is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
>   charset=UTF-8' so you are overriding that value. More info here:
>   [api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

**Update:**

A simple test script worked fine for me. The test action page returns the FORM scope values as a JSON string. The result shows all of the submitted fields:

**result:**

```
{ "TECH_NOTES":"this is a test note"
   , "FIELDNAMES":"TECH_NOTES,TICKET_ID"
   , "TICKET_ID":123
}
```

**action.cfm**

```
<cfoutput>#serializeJSON(form)#</cfoutput>
```

**testForm.cfm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<!--- Javascript that updates the notes in the DB --->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#notesForm').submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            ajaxAddNotes();
        });

    function ajaxAddNotes() {
            console.log("ajaxAddNotes function called");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: $('#notesForm').serialize(),
                url: "action.cfm",
                cache: false,
                //contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $('.loader').show();
                },
                complete: function(){
                     $('.loader').hide(3000);
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#addFileResponse").append( data.toString());
                    // not sure what this method does. comment out for now
                    //PopulateNotesDIV();
                    },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <!--- set sample value --->   
  <cfset get_ticket.tech_notes = "this is a test note">
  <cfset url.ticketID = "123">

  <form name="notesForm" id="notesForm">
    <!--- only need to place around CF variables --->
    <cfoutput>
    <textarea class='expanding' tabindex="18" name="tech_notes" id="tech_notes" cols="100" rows="5" >#get_ticket.tech_notes#</textarea><br />
    <input tabindex="0" type="submit" name="update-notes" id="update-notes" value="Update Notes" />
    <input type="hidden" value="#url.ticketID#" name="ticket_id" id="ticket_id">
    </cfoutput>
    <div class="loader"><img class="loading-image" src="../images/loading.gif" /></div>
    <div class="response" id="addFileResponse"></div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just to add to the answer; by default contentType is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' so you are overriding that value. More info here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Removing both contentType:false and processDate: false has no effect.

Comment: Works fine for me. Perhaps something is different on your end. Can you try the test code above?

Comment: Good addition @JohnWhish. I added your comments to the main answer so it is more visible.

Comment: Thanks for all you help. It is now working. The change I made to my script that finally fixed it was removing var formData = new FormData(); ajaxAddNotes(formData);. I noticed your example didn't define that and wasn't passing it along to the ajaxAddNotes(); function like mine was.

Comment: I do not see that in the OP. Guess that is the "something different on your end". You were using different code than what you posted ;-) Glad it is working now.